# How to open a webpage in default browser after system reboot with nsis installer

Tags: nsis

I am creating a installer. And after installation is finished I have to reboot my system. After reboot I need to open a webpage in default browser. How can I do that with nsis script?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two installers:

1) Your main installer - it does all your stuff and at the end it writes the registry key and copies the File to run after reboot:

```
WriteRegStr "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" "Program Name" "$INSTDIR\File.exe"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "File.exe"
```

**File.exe** is application from point 2). It is good to save it in your app. installation folder.

2) Installer (or better to say simple application in NSIS) which is run after reboot and opens the website (and quits immediately):

```
Function .onInit  
  ExecShell "open" "http://www.visual-installer.com/" SW_SHOWNORMAL
  Quit
FunctionEnd
```

(just fragments of script)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea and you should not do this IMHO.

If you still insist on doing this then you need to decide which user you want to target. Any user? The user that ran the installer? Only Administrators? You don't have control over which user logs in after the reboot.

If you only want to run it for Administrators then you can use the RunOnce solution suggested by Slappy because HKLM RunOnce is only executed by Administrators.

If you want to run it for **any** user then you have to put something in the shared start-menu startup folder. It is important that you use the [AccessControl plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in) to grant `Delete` access for everyone `(WD)`. (We cannot use the Run key in the registry because we cannot apply ACL changes to values, only to keys). You can only do this if your installer is running elevated but I assume it is because only elevated installers can make global changes that require a reboot. You must use `SetShellVarContext all` in NSIS to access the shared `$SMStartup` folder.

You can create a shortcut to something or place the program itself in startup, the important part is that it deletes itself. You can probably get away with using a simple batch file:

```
@echo off
start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsis
del "%~f0"
```